# Firebase: Why we need bindTo method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, firebase

I've recently started to explore Firebase for my Angular JS.
I've two snippets,

```
    var ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase-id.firebaseio.com");

    var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");
```

and

```
    var ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase-id.firebaseio.com");

    $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
```

Now in the view, I have,

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="FirebaseController">
    {{data}}
</div>
```

Both the controller $scope.data objects work equally well for three-way data binding, and the view is updated as soon as the underlying data changes. So my doubt is, what is the difference here? Which one should be chosen (among 'syncObject.$bindTo(..)' and '$scope.data = ..)' and under what conditions.

Please let me know if it's not clear, so I will try to explain further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer myself after some testing.

```
syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data1")
```

actually establishes a bi-directional binding, i.e. if we change the data later using,

```
$scope.data1.xyz = "jjj";
```

It's actually saved back in the firebase database in real-time.

Now the other case,

```
$scope.data2 = $firebaseObject(ref);
```

This is just like a uni-directional bound prototypically inherited object, which gets notified (updated) on the data change in database, but any change on the object itself won't be reflected back on the server.

i.e.

```
$scope.data2.xyz = "jjj"
```

won't update the firebase database, but the local modal only. Any new push update from the database server will overwrite the local changes.

I hope that makes it clear. I've verified the same.

Comment: You are correct. Use `.$bindTo()` sparingly, because three-way data-bindings can have some unintended side effects.

Comment: Correct indeed, as David already said. But, in you explanation, it's probably better to talk about uni-directional and bi-directional instead of argue over the number of ways.